# Inline the Facebook 'Like' button

Tags: html, facebook-like

At the very bottom of [this page](http://www.alliancehealthpartners.com/index.html) I've added some social buttons. No matter what I try, the Facebook 'Like' button goes to its own line. What can I do to keep it on the same line as the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is a `<br>` tag right before the FB Like button.  Can you remove the `<br>`?

Comment: adding to Craig ... it's a br tag. that is putting it in the next line

Comment: Doh! That was it. Thanks!! A 2nd pair of eyes always helps. :)